# Show mysql replication slave status

Tags: php, mysqli, database-replication

How to return the replication server status?

When trying to get the slave status nothing is returned?!

mysql: 5.1.63-0

## code

```
$result = Mysql::result("SHOW SLAVE STATUS");
$status = $result->fetch_assoc();
echo '<pre>';
echo 'result: ';
print_r($result);
echo 'status: ';
print_r($status);
echo '</pre>';
```

## returns

```
result: mysqli_result Object
(
    [current_field] => 0
    [field_count] => 38
    [lengths] => 
    [num_rows] => 0
    [type] => 0
)
status:
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to get the row with the data in it:

$row=$result->fetch_assoc()

Then $row['Slave_IO_Running'] and $row ['Slave_SQL_Running'] should give you what you need.  Both should be yes.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact problem and it turned out I was connecting to the master database handle rather than the slave. Your $result shows num_rows=0 so the problem is not how you're fetching the row; it's that there is no status to show.